# Upgraded my 32 bit machine with 64 bit live image of Ubuntu 14.04 by accident!

Tags: boot, upgrade, 64-bit, freeze, 32-bit

I just upgraded my 64 bit laptop successfully to Ubuntu 14.04 using a 64 bit live image and then upgraded my Desktop with the same 64 bit image forgetting that my desktop is a 32 bit machine.

Now my desktop is stuck at boot screen after "Adding swap...."

Should I download the 32 bit image now to fix my desktop or can it be fixed with the 64 bit image that I already have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your desktop is a 32 bit machine then 64 bit OS cannot be installed. You have to download and install the 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. But is it possible to at least repair the broken 32-bit system by booting with a 64-bit live CD? Like doing chroot and using apt-get to update the packages?